# SharePoint 2013 - How to get document library size?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have this Document Library Monitoring Console App written in C# and its running in SharePoint 2007. We now upgrading our SharePoint Server to 2013, so we also need to upgrade our solutions and customization including console apps.

I search through the web I can't find replace for deprecated "**SPSite.StorageManagementInformation**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.usage.aspx).
You can to use **"SPSite.Usage.Storage"**.

Hope it help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will get back and give updates when I figure it out using your recommendation

Comment: This is just storage of whole Site. It cannot be used for a particular document library